# Read value of variable in a running Windows application process, also after restart

Tags: winapi, readprocessmemory

Is it possible at all to read the value (presumably a variable, since it changes every few seconds and is shown on screen) from a process in Windows? This is some custom, fairly old (10y) Windows GUI application that shows values (part counter) from manufacturing machine connected to it via some proprietary protocol (even using a dedicated PCI commmunications card).

I got the idea when reading about people modifying settings in a game (change high-score, change difficulty level, etc).

On Windows, there is an official API [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) for reading data from a process's memory:

> ReadProcessMemory copies the data in the specified address range from the address space of the specified process into the specified buffer of the current process. Any process that has a handle with PROCESS_VM_READ access can call the function.

While I am hopeful that it works once the address/offset of the value in question is known, I am not so sure if this application will allocate memory differently when started the next time.

This is how I would approach it:

1. continuously, e.g. every second

   - take a screen shot of the application,
   - take a process dump (procdump from sysinternals) of the application
2. analyse the process dump and try to find the location/offset of the value in question
3. compare process dumps from different startups of the application to see if the value is at the same offset

Is this feasible, or is it completely obvious that memory allocation is very dynamic (between restarts and even during runtime) and using an offset-based approach will be doomed?

Comment: It's clearly possible for processes to read memory of other processes (hint: debuggers exist). But you're right that it's so dynamic that you cannot use a hard-coded offset. Is it an option to read the value from the GUI instead? You can think of the windows GUI as a sort of accidental API to the app.

Comment: re: debuggers ;)

yes, reading from GUI would be sufficient (in terms of update frequency) - do you mean screen grabbing and OCR, or really reading somehow from some Winforms or similar component?

Comment: @juwalter depending on how the GUI is setup, you might be able to directly monitor the actual UI control that is displaying the value, and just grab its text whenever it changes. Use a tool like Spy++ to see if the GUI has such a control.